# Android : BottomNavigationView icons are not visible

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, bottomnavigationview

Thanks for stopping by. So my problem here is, the icons from bottom_navigation_menu.xml from menu source file are not visible. I tried Google, Stackoverflow, and here are things that I have tried but still they are not visible: Restart Android Studio, Add selector, Change dependencies to androidX, Class to androidX, re-read the documentation.

Hope someone can help me out...thanks!!!!

I'm using Android Studio 3.6.3, Gradle 6.4

Class file

```
package com.example.todayilearnedbeta;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class AddEntriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addentries);


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_Bar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.ic_main:
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(AddEntriesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                    break;

                case R.id.id_search:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(AddEntriesActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_add_entries:

                    break;

                case R.id.ic_past_entries:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(AddEntriesActivity.this, PastEntriesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_profile:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(AddEntriesActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    break;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
}

}
```

Layout XML codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AddEntriesActivity"
android:background="@drawable/add_entry_activity_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_main"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_main"
    android:title="MainLogo"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="Search"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_add_entries"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_entries"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="AddEntries"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_past_entries"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_past_entries"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="PastEntries"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="Backup"
    />
```

Nav bar item colour selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="ffffff" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="#000000" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Dependencies (here just showing that I implement the latest material dependency.

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
}
```

Comment: are the tabs visible with the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your buttom_navigatiom_menu.xml , add this to set the visibility status

```
 android:visible="true"
```

Make sure you add visibility status cod to each of the icon items

Example

```
<item
android:id="@+id/ic_add_entries"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_entries"
android:visible="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:title="AddEntries"
/>
```

If this does not work for you, try this:

1. Go-to File Menu in Android Studio
2. Invalid Caches & Restart
3. Open existing project

Comment: It's still not visible in mine. I tried testing it out on my own and even copying it altogether. No luck. Maybe, there's something wrong with my dependency.